# Exclude multiple lines from in Bash (Version: 3.2.48)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

The idea is to calculate SHA256 hashes for all files in a directory (including all subdirectories), but exclude some files specified in another text file.

The problem is if I specify the following files (see below the code) to exclude, only one of them is excluded, not both.

Here is my code:

```
while read line
do
    if [ $line_count -eq 0 ]
    then
        exclude_files=".*/$line$"
    else
        exclude_files="${exclude_files}\|.*/$line$"
    fi

    line_count=$(( $line_count + 1 ))
done < exclude-files.txt

find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shasum -a 256 | grep -v -P "${exclude_files}" > ~/out.txt
```

Contents of the file `exclude-files.txt`:

```
Icon\\r
.DS_Store
--- empty line ---
```

The file `Icon\r` is a special file for changing a folder's icon, its name contains a `CR`. (I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.4)

Comment: what is the output of shasum?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul A sample output: `2b3546369548bc18abdc9f76b6fd9b60a551471fad9894e7921fc9c74588d45f  ./folder1/folder2/1.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your variable `\` is recognized as escape symbol for `|`:

```
exclude_files="${exclude_files}\|.*/$line$"
```

you need to add anothers `\` to escape `\` to get it work:

```
exclude_files="${exclude_files}\\|.*/$line$"
```

Also you're using `-P` option in `grep`. In this case you don't need to escape `|`. Therefore you use it without backslash at all.

You should to chose which way you will use: escape or `-P`. Both together they won't work.

Comment: I've gone from `-P` to `-E` and abandoned the escape characters. It works now with every file I specify except with `Icon\r`. I have no idea how to process that.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more, I don't understand what you mean here: "You should to chose which way you will use: escape or -P. Both together they won't work."

Comment: I got it. I'm using `-P` without any other escape characters than `\r` in `Icon\r`. Thanks.
I'll be testing some more, and accept your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

grep would not be safe if filenames contain character with a special meaning, maybe this can help

```
cmd=(find . -type f \( )
while read line;do cmd=("${cmd[@]}" \! -name "$line" -a);done < exclude-files.txt
cmd[${#cmd[*]}-1]=\)
echo "${cmd[@]}" | cat -v
"${cmd[@]}" -print0 | xargs -0 shasum -a 256
```